# really simple SQL Not a GROUP BY expression - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I tried to read about not a group by expression errors from some other posts, but all of them mention group functions such as MAX, MIN, etc. I'm not using any of it and it's a really simple query returning this sort of error.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ad_voarnet_atendimento_pista 
WHERE  is_closed = 0 
GROUP  BY prefixo 
ORDER  BY prefixo
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

The expected result is the same that MySQL would give me with this query. It would exclude every duplicated value of the column PREFIXO. I want only 1 record of each value in the mentioned column.
The error message is this:

```
[Err] ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Comment: What is the exact error message are you getting?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to get what MySQL would give me with this SQL. It would exclude every repeatable value of the column PREFIXO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` is not useful outside of the context of an aggregate function like `MIN() MAX() SUM() COUNT()`, except perhaps to deduplicate rows.  Just remove it.  If you are looking to deduplicate results, use `DISTINCT` instead.  If you use `DISTINCT`, it won't be of much value unless you are more specific about the columns in the `SELECT` list, excluding the primary key column.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT * 
FROM 
  AD_VOARNET_ATENDIMENTO_PISTA 
WHERE IS_CLOSED = 0
ORDER BY PREFIXO
```

`GROUP BY` is sometimes confused with `ORDER BY`.  You already have an `ORDER BY PREFIX0`,

Comment: `DISTINCT * ` is pretty useless as it will include the primary key columns and therefor - by definition - no duplicates can ever be in the result.

Comment: Won't the *DISTINCT* clause make it that every row that is duplicated be excluded? What I want is the same GROUP BY from MySQL would give me: If a result already has such value, it will be ignored, but only for the field that I mentioned.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu MySQL has a very different default behavior of `GROUP BY` that isn't present in other RDBMS.  MySQL allows you to include columns in the `SELECT` which are not also present in `GROUP BY` with sometimes non-deterministic results, but that is not possible in other RDBMS.  What is your input data and what result do you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes-  assuming no PK, or a more specific `SELECT` list.   The OP is apparently  really looking for MySQL's weird and broken behavior.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Learning `GROUP BY` aggregates in MySQL first usually means needing to re-learn how they really work in every other RDBMS, unfortunately.

Comment: So in other words, I'm gonna have to use **SELECT DISTINCT PREFIXO** as subquery?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Not necessarily.  I can't answer without seeing sample data and sample result.  More likely you would need to do something like `PREFIX0, MIN(ID)` in a joined subquery to get one row per `PREFIX0`.

Comment: Both mine and yours solution worked out for me. Thanks :D